# Why is ftell() telling me that the parameter is invalid?

Tags: c

In the debugger, I get an unhandled exception from (ucrtbased.dll) in Executable.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

I believe I am following the parameters of the functions as documented, so I am quite confused as to why this is happening.

The code is from me trying to encrypt a text file by using XOR, if this helps to provide any clarity. Thank you for reading this!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain()
{

    FILE* ptr;
    ptr = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\text.txt", "rb+");
    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    long endpoint = ftell(ptr);     //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Area where Unhandled exception occurs
    char* buffer = malloc(endpoint + 1);
    endpoint = fread(buffer, 1, endpoint, ptr);
    rewind(ptr);
    char* temp = buffer;
    for (int i = 0; i < endpoint; i++, temp++)
    {
        *temp = *temp ^ 21;
    }
    fwrite(temp, 1, endpoint, ptr);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never check that `ptr` is valid.

Comment: In addition, you need to rewind before you read (you fseek'd to the end)

Comment: And if the file is larger than 2GB, this is going to fail because `long` is limited to 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: @LouFranco: I think that you misunderstood the intention. OP attempted to read the file size, in order to know how much memory to allocate for the read buffer.

Comment: `FILE` is already buffered... In this instance, there's no need to duplicate that by loading the entire file.... Looping with `fgetc()` would serve just as well and with simpler code.

Comment: @thebusybee: you are right, I did not read carefully the next line(s). Thanks.